# JasperReports: Some symbols from UTF-8 are lost after exporting to PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report that is exported to XLSX and PDF. The code of both exporters is pretty similar at the same time encoding is lost during PDF export.

For instance, the following symbols are simply skipped in the end result: "Č", "ć". At the same time "ü", "ß" are printed correctly.

In XLSx exporter (**working part**) I use pretty simple code:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    JRXlsxExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
    xlsExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    xlsExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
    xlsExporter.exportReport();
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

In case of PDF I use pretty the same code (**doesn't work**):

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
    exporter.exportReport();
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

But it doesn't work. In both cases I pass the same instance of `jasperPrint`.

I tried playing around with `PdfExporterConfiguration` to set up some parameters, but unfortunately haven't found any encoding related configuration.

**Q:** What might cause the problem? Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspision is that the problem comes from the fonts you are using. Are you sure both XLSX and PDF support the font you have set in your report? In the generated PDF you can check the used font by right-clicking and choosing document properties - there is a tab with fonts. Does the font in PDF support those symbols?

If I remember correctly sometimes when exporting to PDF the exporter will use some different font (if the one you wanted is not found/supported or something).

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure how to check the font in PDF, but in Jasper Studio there was a default font. I also tried changing it to some other fonts but was getting the same result.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota In Jasper Studio there are some options to control PDF exporters default font and encoding - in: window/preferences/jaspersoft studio/exporters/pdf exporter/fonts. No idea if it is possible to set those properties from code. To check what font is used in PDF just right-click anywhere and there should be something like "document properties".

Comment: You are right. Changing the font from 'SansSerif' to 'DejaVu Sans' solved the issue. Now I need to find a font that looks like 'SansSerif' and supports these characters ('DejaVu Sans' looks too different).